# Angular NgRx's Effect creates an infinite loop

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

first of all it is worth mentioning the fact that I still haven't very clear rxjs's operators. I studied them but in the practical act if I either use switchMap, mergeMap or map the result still seems the same.

The code below creates an infinite loop, I tried to place debuggers strategically in order to understand the flow but it must be strictly related to the HTTP response time, hence appears to jump between the effects in a very random way.

```
@Effect()
addNewDocument = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.ADD_DOCUMENT),
    map((action: UserActions.AddNewDocument) => {
        return action.document;
    }),
    switchMap((document: FormData) => {
        return this.store.select('user').pipe(
            map((user) => {
                return {
                    document,
                    uuid: user.uuid
                };
            })
        );
    }),
    switchMap((payload: { document: FormData, uuid: string }) => {
        return this.httpClient.post(
            `${environment.apiUrl}user/${payload.uuid}/documents`,
            payload.document
        ).pipe(
            mergeMap((response: any) => {
                return [
                    {
                        type: UserActions.ADDED_DOCUMENT,
                        response
                    }
                ];
            }),
            catchError((error) => of(new AppActions.GenericError(error)))
        );
    })
);

@Effect({dispatch: false})
addedNewDocument = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.ADDED_DOCUMENT),
    tap(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/user/documents']);
    })
);
```

My intent is:

1. Intercept UserActions.ADD_DOCUMENT action
2. keep track of the uuid for the http request
3. Make the request and handle the response through the event UserActions.ADDED_DOCUMENT in order to update the state through its reducer

I'd really appreciate if you help me to understand what's wrong. If you think I missused some operators or you know a better method to use them, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With the caveat that I’m no expert but I think you need to rewrite using following https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#incorporating-state and pass user through props and possibly the withLatestFrom operator.

Comment: I didn't know that operator. It'll be very useful. Thank you @AndrewAllen

Comment: @AdrianBrand Why is that? I'm working at my very first project with NgRx but I think it's cool, I've just found RxJs operator a little difficult to understand as you can see.

Comment: @zangarmarsh I think Adrian hates the boilerplate problem (he's written his own version of state management) and not all projects need ngrx.

Comment: I just for the life of me cannot see why people like NgRx, it is insane how much abstraction and boilerplate goes into the simple act of calling an api. It sabotages your velocity and gets in the road at every point. Learn how Angular dependency injection works and how to create sane manageable Angular services. Have a read of my article on Angular state management https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `user` state is changing in your application which is causing the looping in the effect. Try using `take(1)` while taking `user` state in effect like this:

```
switchMap((document: FormData) => {
        return this.store.select('user').pipe(
            take(1),
            map((user) => {
                return {
                    document,
                    uuid: user.uuid
                };
            })
        );
    })
```

`take(1)` will complete the observable and will tear down the action until the next `UserActions.ADD_DOCUMENT` action dispatched. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Not necessarily that the user is changing but that when the state changes the selector fires?

Comment: Yes, if user state changes, the selector will emit the new user state.

Comment: How come the operator should be triggered as the user state changes?

Comment: @zangarmarsh That's because in ngrx effects are subscribed by the library and because of state changes, it will trigger the selector. Is the solution worked for you?

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked @user2216584 . I don't really get what brings on the loop tho. Is the 'select' method that fires every time the state changes?

Comment: @zangarmarsh Yes! as mentioned in my earlier comments, if user state is changing then your `select` will be called. To avoid that `take(1)` will do the trick.